# Formatting Calculated field in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, formatting

I'm using SQL Server 2008. I've a calculated field - PercentChange, which is defined as Round(100*(a-b)/b,2). And my query is structured as

```
Select x.* from
(
 *query goes here, PercentChange defined here* 
) as x
where x.Percentchange >50
```

The problem is the PercentChange field gets formatted as an Object(!) and I am not able to add a '%' sign to it. As You can probably guess, I'm not an expert at this. So can anyone please suggest a workaround to display 'PercentChange' of 60.55 as 60.55%?

Comment: Better to do it on the presentation layer (i.e. in your front end application). Because, once you add `%` mark, it becomes a string and you won't be able to use that field for any calculation purposes without doing string manipulations again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is SQL server use this

```
Select cast(x.Percentchange as varchar) + '%', x.oteherfield, ...
from(
    *query goes here, PercentChange defined here* 
    ) as x
where x.Percentchange >50
```

or something like this for other dialects.

Comment: Obviously, it is not job for sql server but presentation layer, anyway it is exact answer for your question.